# Website access control

Tags: php, security, nginx, web-deployment, access-control

I'm currently working on adding a login system to an old website. Unfortunately, I'm new to web developments and can not find answers for the following questions:
1. How can I check if a user is logged in or not before serving his http requests. I do understand that in pho we just add session_start() follow by some checking statements. But the website I'm working on is really big and can would be tedious to add session check statement in every page. so is there a way to check if a user is logged in before serving his/her request?

The server is using nginx and the website is using php.

Thanks

Comment: If there is too many pages then you should create a seperete file that does all the authentication then you can include that into every file that you would like to restrict access

Comment: This is what I'm planning to avoid. So, is there any kind of a way to first route all http requests to a single php page and that page will decide if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: That is normally implemented in the MVC patterns. [MVC Tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)